# Mypy error "Need more than 2 values to unpack (3 expected)" although union of different tuples is used

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

When I run mypy  on the following code I get

> Need more than 2 values to unpack (3 expected)

How do I fix this?

```
def func(third: bool = False) -> tuple[int, int] | tuple[int, int, int]:
    if third:
        return 1, 2, 3
    else:
        return 1, 2
        
a, b, c = func(True) # mypy error line
```

`func` is in fact returning three values in this case. I'm using Python 3.10.4.

Comment: as @VladimirObrizan mentioned, alternative syntax for unions requires Python 3.10 or newer, and the sample works OK in Python 3.10

Comment: The problem is that mypy reports the error I reprinted in the question.

Comment: Dear @foosion, I tested this snippet with Python v3.10.4 on CLI, and it works without  any error/exception.

Comment: @BurakÖzalp I'm not sure why you aren't getting mypy errors. See the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Described situation is a typical use case for [overloading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload).

You can annotate the function such that for `True` argument it returns 3-tuple and for `False` - 2-tuple:

```py
from typing import overload, Literal

@overload
def func(third: Literal[True]) -> tuple[int, int, int]: 
    ...
@overload
def func(third: Literal[False] = ...) -> tuple[int, int]:
    ...
    
def func(third: bool = False) -> tuple[int, int] | tuple[int, int, int]:
    if third:
        return 1, 2, 3
    else:
        return 1, 2
        
a, b, c = func(True)
a, b = func(False)
a, b = func()
```

[Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=0d8bdf91207e8c2c0b2ea479522171ac)

The problem in your current code is that `mypy` doesn't know whether return type will be 2-tuple or 3-tuple. It does not make additional assumptions looking at implementation, type hints are strict. Your code could look like this (interpreted by `mypy` exactly the same way):

```py
import random
def func(three: bool = False) -> tuple[int, int] | tuple[int, int, int]:
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        return 1, 1
    else:
        return 1, 1, 1

a, b, c = func()
```

... And now your code fails in (approx) 50% cases and `mypy` points to that error.

Comment: That works.  Not as simple as I hoped.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) to declare that `func` has a different return type depending on the argument.

```
from typing import Literal, overload

@overload
def func(third: Literal[True]) -> tuple[int, int, int]:
    ...
@overload
def func(third: Literal[False]) -> tuple[int, int]:
    ...
def func(third: bool = False):
    if third:
        return 1, 2, 3
    else:
        return 1, 2
```

Comment: I believe you need the return type in the actual func def `tuple[int, int] | tuple[int, int, int]:' and then this works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue with Mypy: [Cannot unpack Union of Tuples of different length](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7965).

Here is my proposal how to fix the given example, so it works and Mypy shows no errors:

```
from typing import Optional, Tuple


def func(third: bool = False) -> Tuple[int, int, Optional[int]]:
    if third:
        return 1, 2, 3
    else:
        return 1, 2, None


a, b, c = func(True)

print(a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
```

Mypy run:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: That works. However, the old version would run (but not pass mypy) with `a, b = func(False)` while this gets `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @foosion you can't run a, b = func(False), because it will not pass mypy.

Comment: Not passing mypy was the reason for this question. Please see the two `overload` responses.